# why iOS App terminating due to NSRangeException

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, nsrangeexception

I'm having a weird error popping up. It's listing that my app is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

What puzzles me is that the app runs perfectly fine in the simulator, but when I go to test it on my device I get that error. I've isolated the problem to the line of code below:

```
updatingTracker = [userDatas objectAtIndex:repeatCount];
```

Here is the rest of the relevant code:

```
[self getUserDatas];
[self timerDidFire];

-(void) getUserDatas
{
    userDatas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *userdef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int count = [[userdef objectForKey:@"user_count"] intValue];
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        NewTracker *newtrack=[[NewTracker alloc] init];
        newtrack.FromCurrency = [userdef objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"from_string_%d",i]];
        newtrack.ToCurrency   = [userdef objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"to_string_%d",i]];
        newtrack.savedCurrency = [userdef objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"save_currency_%d",i]];
        newtrack.userTarget = [userdef objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_target_%d",i]];
        newtrack.trackerId = [userdef objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tracker_id_%d",i]];
        newtrack.realtimeBase = [userdef objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"realtime_base_%d",i]];
        newtrack.realtimeTarget = [userdef objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"realtime_target_%d",i]];
        newtrack.realtimeUSD = [userdef objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"realtime_USD_%d",i]];
        [userDatas addObject:newtrack];
    }
}

- (void) timerDidFire
{
    NSLog(@"bug finder");

    updatingTracker = [userDatas objectAtIndex:repeatCount];
    [self chartconnectionStart:@"3m"];
}
```

Any ideas or help on why this is happening or how to fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. `count` is probably being set as 0 so you allocate your array but never add any objects to it, and when you try and access it you get the `NSRangeException` error. Try with `int count = 10` and see what happens - if it works you know where to look next.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Caused other errors but now I at least understand what's going on. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your userDatas array is empty. You most likely don't have anything populated in your user defaults on your phone, so the code that adds to the array is never executed. You probably have some data already populated on your simulator and that's why it's not working on the phone

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks!

Comment: I commented out the line [self timerDidFire] and it completely fixed the app. It shouldn't have been firing on app launch because like you said, there is no data in the user defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Simple put a conditional breakpoint on that line for the condition `[userDatas count] == 0`. Or put in an `if` to catch that and a breakpoint on it. They use the debugger to figure out how you got there and what the associated values are.

Basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Code like this

- (void) timerDidFire{

  NSLog(@"bug finder");

  if([userDatas count]>0){

  updatingTracker = [userDatas objectAtIndex:repeatCount];

  [self chartconnectionStart:@"3m"];

  }

}

Happy coding..........